# How to keep original "date created" when copying via Terminal?

Tags: command-line, copy-paste, rsync

There are many questions online asking how to make the commands `rsync` and `cp` go about copying a file while keeping the "date created" attribute the same as the original instead of the time of copy. I understand this is Mac's added information and is separate from the file's **metadata** "date created" attribute. Anyways, as I played around with `rsync -a`, it did everything I wanted except, as everyone online notes, it changed the "date created" to the time of copy instead of original make. With `rsync` and `cp` it changes due to ["a change to the inode"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61586/how-to-tell-rsync-to-preserve-time-stamp-on-files-when-source-tree-has-a-mounted#comment-87540). Command-c command-v, however, keeps the "date created" time the same.

**Here's my question:** How is it that <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> keeps the date created attribute the same on the copy, yet no command in the terminal will yield this result? If <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> can do it, it seems there has to be some command in the Terminal that replicates this?

Comment: Where did you verify whether the dates change or stay the same, in Terminal or in Finder? As can be easily verified using `stat -s`, even Cmd-C/Cmd-V changes `ctime` and `ctime` information, so which timestamps do you want to stay the same here?

Comment: If XCode is installed Getfilinfo file returns the file info. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/GetFileInfo.1.html

Comment: 'NIX does not have a "date created" attribute (unlike Windows). `st_ctime` in the struct stat actually records the last time the inode changed. 

OS X 64 bit has `st_birthtimespec; /* time of file creation(birth) */` but accessing this is not straightforward.

Comment: Patrix: is there a way to view "stat -s <name of file>" with yyyy/mm/dd format for each date returned? And I am trying to get Finder's "created" date to stay the same.

Comment: Scott and Milliways, thank you, I do not have much time right now, I'll check your answers later today.

Answer (score 5):

There are many reasons why one would rather use RSync instead of cp. RSync's default version on MacOS is 2.6.9, which is more than 12 years old as of today, and has several known bugs, and this is one of them. Apple won't include the updated versions on the new releases of the Mac OSX because of GPL3-related stuff.

To address this issue:

1. Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) in your Mac, if you don't have it already

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

2. Install the new version of rsync available on brew:

```
brew install rsync
```

3. Verify that your rsync version is at least 3.1.3:

```
rsync --version
```

4. Copy your files using the --times and --crtimes

```
rsync --times --crtimes /sourcedirectory /destinationdirectory
```

Comment: I believe this should be `--times` and not `-times`.

Answer (score 4):

On 10.10.4, using `cp -p /path/to/source /path/to/destination` the time created is preserved. More specifically, in Finder, *date created* and *date modified* are preserved, while *date added* will have the copy time.

Comment: I believe `cp -a` can replace `-p` as it will copy a directory tree too.

Comment: Not working on 10.14 Mojave. Date modified is being copied to the new file's created date. [same for `cp` & `ditto`]

Answer (score 2):

As stated POSIX does not define "date created" and command line tools are written to POSIX standards but may extend the standards. The behavior of rsync and cp are what is expected. Some file systems and kernels extend the standards and include birthtime or btime.

Assuming you are copying files to the same file system then OS X has tools that will attempt to preserve birthtime ("date created"). You could use `pax` or `hardlink` files and the "date created" will be preserved. Less reliable tools are `ditto` or `cp` with the `p` option (at least on my system, I suspect bugs in HFS+).

If you want to copy files to another file system then you need to  compile rsync with the patches fileflags, crtimes, hfs-compression and rsync can handle OS X metadata and preserve the original file's birthtime on the new file.